# String Trimming Exception

Tags: java, string

Hey Guys i have a weird Problem,
I want to parse a Channel Template from a Website.
What works:
Parsing File and cutting from the Beginning (e.g only German Channels), but cuting from the end of a Line always ends up in a Index out of Range -1 Exception
Dont know why.

Disclamer: This is only a Dummy File the channels are not working!!
So don't except free TV or something.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    {
        String url = "http://www.vjackson.info//live/index";
        final String USER_AGENT = "VAVOO/1.51";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        final String trimFromLine = "no mather whats in here it dont work";
        final String searchKey = "#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name=\"13TH STREET FHD";
        String result = "";

        // Send post request

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine = "";
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
            if (response.toString().contains(searchKey)) {
                result=response.toString().substring(response.toString().indexOf(searchKey));

                String result2 = result.substring(0, result.indexOf(trimFromLine));

            }


        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(result);

        //print result


    }

}
}
```

Comment: What's with the two opening braces at the start of the method?

Comment: @C0nvert500 Do you know where the error is? (Which line?)

Comment: before there was a try catch method.
I removed it for now, but forgot about the braces ^^

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at TestJSON.main(TestJSON.java:46)

Comment: `String.IndexOf(trimFromLine)` will return -1 if it doesn't find `trimFromLine` so it will result in a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you call `result.substring(...)`.

Comment: @n00dl3 Answers in the answer box please!

Comment: ok thanks but why it doesn't find anything?
even if write something in there what exists.
If gives me the same error
Sry for my bad english

Comment: @C0nvert500 Have it `System.out.print` each line that contains the search key as it goes to make sure it's getting what you expect. If not, adjust your program to the actual lines. You can find which line is causing the issue because it will be the line just before the exception is thrown.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Using a debugger and setting breakpoints will require writing less code that will need to be later removed, and it will provide the user with more information at each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result.indexOf(trimFromLine)` returns `-1` when `trimFromLine` isn't found in `result`. If you attempt to run `String.substring(0, -1)`, you will get the same `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` that you are seeing.

You should check if this is the case before attempting to invoke this method:

```
int indexOfTrim = result.indexOf(trimFromLine);
String result2;

if (indexOfTrim > -1) {
    result2 = result.substring(0, indexOfTrim);
}
```

I suspect that the `result2` assignment is causing the problem. Compare result and `trimFromLine` and see what you get. Also check the result of `result.indexOf(trimFromLine)`.

Comment: Maybe it's a Dump Question but if i print out the result variable
result=response.toString().substring(response.toString().indexOf(searchKey));

and look into the string i see the keyword wich i want to set as the second trim point. So i dont understand why it isn't get found

Comment: @C0nvert500 I suspect that line is working fine, and that the `result2` assignment is causing the problem. Compare `result` and `trimFromLine` and see what you get. Also check the result of `result.indexOf(trimFromLine)`. If the strings appear identical, it could be a whitespace or encoding issue.

Comment: Thank you buddy i found the Failure 
It's because this line really don't contains the word.
I thought that the whole text is in the String after he found the first Keyword, but the "result" only contains the first line till the break

m3u list contains a Header (the name of a Channel) and the bottom (IP Adresse)
I thought he save this all together in a row, like text without a break, but he save it's like different lines of text.

Any Ideas how to solve this? I need to trimm the last lines.

Comment: EDIT SOLVED my Problem.
Your Comment helped me thanks
Is some one interested in the Solution?

Comment: @C0nvert500 Glad to hear it! If you found this answer helpful, please mark it solved so others who encounter similar issues can easily find the solution. I have updated my answer to include the relevant portion of the comments that helped you find the answer you needed.